# Valgrind output interpretation assistance needed

Tags: c, valgrind

I'm relatively new to C programming and I have been asked to check a linux utility for buffer overflows, however I have limited knowledge regarding the area so pardon me if I have not done a great job at it. I used Valgrind to detect the overflows and in it I received one definite leak, so I applied the **--leak-check-full** to identify where the leak will potentially be from, but I'm not sure how I can proceed with this, can anyone help me?

The utility I chose was **nstat**. Here's my result:

```
  valgrind --leak-check=full nstat -d 1111111111                        
                                               
==3749== Memcheck, a memory error detector                             
==3749== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.      
==3749== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info        
==3749== Command: nstat -d 1111111111        
==3749==                        
#kernel                        
IpInReceives                    112                0.0   
IpInDelivers                    112                0.0     
IpOutRequests                   115                0.0    
TcpActiveOpens                  6                  0.0     
TcpInSegs                       30                 0.0    
TcpOutSegs                      32                 0.0    
TcpRetransSegs                  1                  0.0    
UdpInDatagrams                  82                 0.0    
UdpOutDatagrams                 82                 0.0      
Ip6InReceives                   2                  0.0      
Ip6InDelivers                   2                  0.0     
Ip6OutRequests                  2                  0.0      
Ip6OutNoRoutes                  2                  0.0      
Ip6InMcastPkts                  2                  0.0       
Ip6OutMcastPkts                 2                  0.0      
Ip6InOctets                     186                0.0      
Ip6OutOctets                    186                0.0       
Ip6InMcastOctets                186                0.0       
Ip6OutMcastOctets               186                0.0       
Ip6InNoECTPkts                  2                  0.0        
Udp6InDatagrams                 2                  0.0        
Udp6OutDatagrams                2                  0.0        
TcpExtTW                        2                  0.0        
TcpExtTCPHPHits                 6                  0.0         
TcpExtTCPPureAcks               5                  0.0        
TcpExtTCPHPAcks                 6                  0.0      
TcpExtTCPTimeouts               1                  0.0      
TcpExtTCPSynRetrans             1                  0.0     
TcpExtTCPOrigDataSent           12                 0.0     
TcpExtTCPDelivered              18                 0.0     
IpExtInMcastPkts                4                  0.0     
IpExtOutMcastPkts               4                  0.0      
IpExtInOctets                   10138              0.0      
IpExtOutOctets                  9060               0.0      
IpExtInMcastOctets              292                0.0       
IpExtOutMcastOctets             292                0.0        
IpExtInNoECTPkts                112                0.0       
==3749==      
==3749== HEAP SUMMARY:     
==3749==     in use at exit: 18,429 bytes in 725 blocks      
==3749==   total heap usage: 756 allocs, 31 frees, 34,350 bytes allocated     
==3749==       
==3749== 128 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 9        
==3749==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)       
==3749==    by 0x10C79D: ??? (in /usr/bin/nstat)          
==3749==    by 0x4BE00B2: (below main) (libc-start.c:308)           
==3749==              
==3749== LEAK SUMMARY:             
==3749==    definitely lost: 128 bytes in 1 blocks         
==3749==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks            
==3749==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks           
==3749==    still reachable: 18,301 bytes in 724 blocks            
==3749==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks          
==3749== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.      
==3749== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all      
==3749==                       
==3749== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s          
==3749== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

I have searched for similar output results on the Valgrind manual but did not come across any. It would be great if someone can tell me what I can do to proceed on with my analysis.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Would you mind typing the valgrind output in your answer instead of linking to an image?

Comment: Also, you've only included the end of valgrind's output.  Could you show the entire output?

Comment: Just to clarify, don't *type* the valgrind output, but *copy and paste* it.

Comment: You'll have to compile a version of `nstat` with debugging information to be able to get any really useful `valgrind` output.

Comment: @Shawn  I'm not sure how to that , is there any way you can give me some guidance?

Comment: `I'm not sure how to that` First - find the program sources. You can query your linux system and see what package name was used to install the executable. `pacman -Ql | grep nstat` gives me `iproute2` on my linux. Then browse net to find the sources of the program. iproute2 is on [kernel.org](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/network/iproute2/iproute2.git), but I see there's up-to-date [github clone](https://github.com/shemminger/iproute2). Then read the documentation of the project about how to compiler the project. The handy README has even a section about "how to compile this". but...

Comment: .... but to be honest it's not really helpfull. On my archlinux I can see how packages are build, [that's really helpfull](https://github.com/archlinux/svntogit-packages/blob/packages/iproute2/trunk/PKGBUILD#L44). It seems the project is build with a `configure` script then with a `Makefile`. Find out if you can compile the project and run the executable. If you can, go edit the [Makefile](https://github.com/shemminger/iproute2/blob/main/Makefile#L55) and add `-g` debug flags and remove `-O<number>` optimization flags from compiler options and recompile again.

Comment: Then run valgrind against executable compiled with debugging symbols - you'll see the function name and full stack of functions which allocated memory. Then you can track which function allocated the memory and why didn't it free it, potentially create a patch and send that patch to one of the maintainers, hopefully the email addresses in README are correct.

Comment: @KamilCuk I did get the code from github and I totally understand about the README file instructions... I tried following it but it just did not compile and kept showing me errors, that's why I decided to use about 50 test cases to test it on the command line itself and if any errors pop up, then go through the code manually change it since it is not that large or complex. But this has been insanely helpful, I will see what I can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are checking for buffer overflows, then rest assured, leaks do not fall into that category. However, your job is far from done. There are two major items that you need to consider.

The first is your code coverage. Just one test is probably far from enough. Ideally you should have an entire test suite that also has measurements of test coverage.

Secondly, there is the question of which is the best tool. One of the things that Valgrind memcheck does *not* do is check for overruns of statically allocated and global variables. Memory that is dynamically allocated (with malloc or new) *will* be checked.

In order to check statically allocated and global variables, I recommend that you use address sanitizer. However, this will entail rebuilding `nstat`.